# Removing char from string in pascal cause question marks in console pascal

Tags: encoding, console, pascal, freepascal

I am trying write simple program that will remove all 'o' letters from the string.
Example :

```
I love cats
```

Output:

```
I lve cats
```

I wrote following code :

```
var 
    x:integer;
    text:string;
    text_no_o:string;
begin
text:='I love cats';
   for x := 0  to  Length(text) do
   //writeln(Ord(text[6]));
   if(Ord(text[x])=111) then    
   else
    text_no_o[x]:=text[x];
    write(text_no_o);
   end.
   begin
   end;
end.
```

When text is in English program works fine .
But if i change it to Russian . It returns we question marks in console.
Code with small modifications for Russian language.

```
var 
    x:integer;
    text:string;
    text_no_o:string;
begin
text:='Русский язык мой родной';
   for x := 0  to  Length(text) do
   //writeln(Ord(text[6]));
   if(Ord(text[x])=190) then    
   else
    text_no_o[x]:=text[x];
    write(text_no_o);
   end.
   begin
   end;
end.
```

And result in console that i receive is :

```
Русский язык м�й р�дн�й
```

I expect receive

```
Русский язык мй рднй
```

As I got the problem can be caused incorrect encoding settings in console, so i should force pascal to use CP1252 instead ANSI .

I am using Free Pascal Compiler version 3.2.0+dfsg-12 for Linux .
P.S I am not allowed to use StringReplace or Pos

Comment: If you remove all letters from `'I love cats '` you end up with `'   '`.

Comment: Sorry . My mistake . I mean remove all 'o' letters.

Comment: No, it does not execute fine with English.  As written, it generates a SIGSGEV exception on the line ` text_no_o[x]:=text[x]`.  You might find it instructive to figure out why ...

Comment: I tried more simple code and it still behavoir same way 
`if(Ord(text[counter])=111) then `
       `write(text[counter]);`

Comment: @MartynA  If i understand correctly it happends because i am using the method Lenght that returns me length stating from one. But my array is staring from zero that possibly cause the problem .

Comment: Use a debugger. Read about single and compound statements. Reason about why a loop from 0 to N does N+1 iterations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is likely to be UTF8 encoded. So the cyrillic o is encoded as two chars $d0 $be. Here you replace one $be (=190). You need to replace both chars, though you cannot just test for the value of the char, because their meaning depends of surrounding chars.

Here is a way, remembering the current state (outside of letter or after first byte)

```
var
  c: char;
  text: string;
  state: (sOutside, sAfterD0);
begin
  text:= 'Русский язык мой родной';
  state:= sOutside;
  for c in text do
  begin
    if state = sOutside then
    begin
      if c = #$D0 then // may be the start of the letter
        state := sAfterD0
      else
        write(c); // output this char because not part of letter
    end
    else if state = sAfterD0 then
    begin
      if c = #$BE then state := sOutside // finished skipping
      else
      begin
        // chars do not form letter so output skipped char
        write(#$D0, c);
        state := sOutside;
      end;
    end
  end;
  writeln;
end.
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution:

```
function Simple_StripO (Text : String) : String;
var 
  i : integer;
  Text2 : string;
begin
  Text2 := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(Text) do
    if Text[i] <> 'o' then
      Text2 := Text2 + Text[i];
  Result := Text2;  // Or Simple_StripO := Text2;
end;
```

Comment: @AlexZaslavskis, you need to compare with the cyrillic letter `о`.

Comment: I do it. I changed it to ' о ' and it not really help.  Also usage of Ansi and Ord display me question marks in console